# Caffeine cache with spring boot not working

Tags: spring-boot, caffeine-cache

I've set up a scenario using caffeine cache and I can't get it working, the real method is always called when the parameters are the same. Here is my config:

pom.xml

```xml
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

Configuration class for the CacheManager

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {

    public static final String CACHE_NAME = "test";

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager(CACHE_NAME);
        cacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeineConfig());
        return cacheManager;
    }

    private Caffeine caffeineConfig() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(1024 * 1024 * 256);
    }
}
```

And then the class with the cacheable method:

```java
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {CachingConfig.CACHE_NAME})
public class MyClass{

  @Cacheable
   public Object cacheableMethod(String a, String b, Boolean c) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new Object()
}
```

I've tried also adding the cache name to the Cacheable annotation:

```java
@Cacheable(value = CachingConfig.CACHE_NAME)
```

And moving `@EnableCaching` to the Spring Boot main application class.

The real method is always been called.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @Cacheable method has to be located inside a @Bean, @Component, @Service...